# Sending SMS from an application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I have used SmsManager to send a SMS from my application. The code is shown below

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phone_number, null, message, sentPI, null);
```

I am using a broadcastReceiver as a listener for the above SMS task. the broadcastReceiver will call it's onReceive listener method to indicate that the sms is sent. This listener is placed in onResume() method of my activty

```
context.registerReceiver( br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.w("MainActivity", "SMS is sent");
                     // TO-DO sms is sent, display the user
                    break;
                }
           }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

everything is working fine with the logic. The problem arises when i leave the activity and before i get back to my app the SMS is sent.Since in the onPause method i have unregistered the service there is no listener here And my activity UI s not updated.

Is there anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: What line of code is throwing the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I have updated the qsn I think it will be clear now.

Comment: I would create a separate file for the `BroadcastReceiver` to catch the sent intent and update your database, then in your activity in onresume query the DB and update the UI.